# Clear data from Clip/AudioStream to free up memory

Tags: java, out-of-memory, clip

I have some code that serves as a super basic music player:

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;

public class MusicPlayer{

private Clip c;
private boolean playing;

public MusicPlayer(){
    playing = false;
}

public void play(String fileName) {
    if(playing == false){
        try {
            c.drain();
            c.flush();
            AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(fileName));
            c = AudioSystem.getClip();
            c.open(audioInputStream);
            c.start();
            playing = true;
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error with playing sound:" + ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void stop(){
    if(playing == true){
        c.stop();
        playing = false;
    }
}
```

}

The problem is that if I try to open too many wav files, the program crashes with an OutOfMemoryError. Giving the program more memory to work with (less than ideal to begin with) still means that the program runs slower each time a new file is opened. You can see I tried to solve this with:

```
c.drain();
c.flush();
```

but plainly this is not enough. Any help is appreciated!